# Adding columns and rows to table in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way in which a table can be made of variable rows and columns having text fields where data can be entered.UItableView have only 1 column and not more than 1 column.

Thanks

Comment: UITableView has as many rows as you need. You can create each cell using code and emulate rows, and maybe mount it on a scrollview for horizontal scroll once the cell is bigger than the screen width. First step is to create a custom UITableViewController. You could also explain your use case to see if you are best served using a grid.

Comment: sorry but can't attach the image as it is not allowed by the site policies.I actually wanted a table having text fields which are filled by the user as well as drop down menus for user to choose. I have about 5 textfields and 3 drop downs.can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this post for some sample code about drawing a grid in your table view:
[Drawing a Grid in a UITableView](http://www.chirpware.com/posts/14176.html). This is one possibility to customize a table view so that it shows multiple columns.

The sample uses `UILabel` objects to fill the individual cells. So you might also find an easy way to make them appear editable (or use UITextField instead of UILabel in `ableView cellForRowAtIndexPath`).

Answer (score 0):

you can customize your UITableViewCell to behave as if they were multiple column, but it is quite unusual to edit cell directly.

Better handle cell selection, then display a detailed view you can edit.