# uiTableView in Uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I wanted to have a tableview which i should be able to scroll horizontally.So i thought of adding a tableview in uiscrollview and then populating the custom cells in it.
Is it the correct way to do it.I have checked on developer site and it is stated that  You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects.     **If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled**.
Does anyone has implemented such thing.And can anyone help please?

Comment: The default configuration just works. Create a [custom tableview controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744304/are-there-anyone-that-use-tableviewcontroller-without-subclassing/6744475#6744475) and embed it normally.

Comment: @jano u mean we can put a tableview object over a uiscrollview object in a viewcontroller to make tableview to scroll horizontally.as far as i know,tableview can't be made to scroll horizontally.

Comment: please refer to this question of mine.maybe u would understand my problem better..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645063/adding-columns-and-rows-to-table-in-iphone

Comment: You can scroll a table horizontally if you apply a 90º transform to the table. Here is a tutorial with a horizontal scrolling table mounted on a UIScrollView: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1